# Javascript integer to string casting not working

Tags: javascript

Hello there I'm somewhat new to Javascript and I was trying to create a simple password generator. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems to stop working at around my switch statement. I was just curious as to what I may be doing wrong, I think something may be wrong  with how I'm casting my integers into Strings.

```
function generate(){
var lower=document.getElementById('c1').checked;
var upper=document.getElementById('c2').checked;
var number=document.getElementById('c3').checked;
var extend=document.getElementById('c4').checked;
var special=document.getElementById('c5').checked;
var space=document.getElementById('c6').checked;
var chars=new Array();
var types=0;
chars[0]=0;
chars[1]=1;
chars[2]=2;
chars[3]=3;
chars[4]=4;
chars[5]=5;
var password="";
for(i=0;i<16;i++){
var rnd=chars[randomFromInterval(0,5)];
    switch(rnd)
    {//This Part Isn't Working
        case 0:password+=((char)(randomFromInterval(97,122)));break;
        case 1:password+=randomFromInterval(65,90).toString();break;
        case 2:password+=((char)(randomFromInterval(60,71)));break;
        case 3:password+=((char)(randomFromInterval(48,57)));break;
        case 4:password+=((char)(randomFromInterval(33,47)));break;
        case 5:password+=(char)(32);break;
    }
}
document.getElementById("password").value =password;

function randomFromInterval(from,to)
{
return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
}
```

Comment: There are probably multiple things wrong. When I just try to evaluate your code, I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not have a cast operator. It also does not have a `char` type.

What you write as `(char)x` is written as `String.fromCharCode(x)` in JavaScript.